# Using PowerShell to verify if a Windows Service isn't running and send an email with information

Tags: powershell, server, service, sendmail

I have this powershell code already created.
It runs and sends an email with details of each remote machine, service and what seems to be the status.

However the service name and status appear to not function correctly. The output from this script tells me that the service isn't found. However, I've checked this by just running this on the same machine I ran this full script to validate the services are present and identify the status of the actual service;

```
Get-Service -ComputerName machine1 -Name MyService
```

My full PowerShell script is below;

```
# Define the list of machine names where the service should be checked
$machineNames = @("machine1","machine2")  # Add more machine names as needed

# Define the service name to check
$serviceName = "MyService"

# Function to check service status on a specific machine
function Get-ServiceStatus {
param (
    [string]$machineName,
    [string]$service
)

$serviceStatus = Get-Service -ComputerName $machineName -Name $service -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue
if ($serviceStatus) {
    return $serviceStatus.Status
} else {
    return "Service Not Found"
}
}

# Initialize an empty array to store information about services that are not running
$notRunningServices = @()

# Check the service status on each machine
foreach ($machine in $machineNames) {
$status = Get-ServiceStatus -machineName $machine -service $serviceName
if ($status -ne "Running") {
    $notRunningServices += [PSCustomObject]@{
        MachineName = $machine
        ServiceName = $serviceName
        Status = $status
    }
}
}

# If there are services not running, send an email
if ($notRunningServices.Count -gt 0) {
$smtpServer = "smtp.server.com"
$smtpPort = 25
$fromAddress = "from@email.com"  
$toAddress = "to@email.com"

$emailSubject = "MyService Service Status - Not Running"
$emailBody = "The following services are not running:`r`n`r`n"

foreach ($service in $notRunningServices) {
    $emailBody += "Server: $($service.MachineName)`r`nService: 
$($service.ServiceName)`r`nStatus: $($service.Status)`r`n`r`n"
}

Send-MailMessage -From $fromAddress -To $toAddress -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody - 
SmtpServer $smtpServer -Port $smtpPort
}
```

I need to resolve the powershell script to identify the remote service name on each machine.

A copy of the email is here;

**The following services are not running:**

Server: machine1
Service: MyService
Status: Service Not Found

Server: machine2
Service: MyService
Status: Service Not Found

Would really appreciate if someone could please help.

Thanks in advance

NOTE: With thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/21272873/toddy-s, he is correct in saying that I'm running this via a scheduled task.

Comment: Knowing that a scheduled task is involved is certainly a crucial piece of information that should have been mentioned up front.  By itself, it isn't enough to diagnose your problem. Your code blindly assumes that not getting a result from `Get-Service` is tantamount to "Service not found", which isn't necessarily true, and probably obscures the true problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script and it works in my test environment.

Result checking a member server (TESTSRV) and a DC (TESTDC) for ActiveDirectoryWebService (ADWS):

```
$notRunningServices    

MachineName ServiceName Status           
----------- ----------- ------           
TESTSRV     ADWS        Service Not Found
```

I assume you're running this as a scheduled task.

Maybe a permission problem?

---

Update:

If you want to access network resources in a script started by task scheduler, you have to start the task with a user account with sufficient permissions.

The default account "System" is only allowed to access the local server.

You can change this on the "General" tab of your task.

Comment: While there's good information in your post in the sense of encouraging the OP to _clarify their question_, it isn't an answer per se, and better suited to being posted in the form of a _comment_ (the latter requires a reputation level of 50 points or more).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).